# Python code to install Firefox.exe inside command line

Tags: python, firefox

I am using the below code to run Mozilla Firefox .exe file in Python code.

```
import os
os.startfile("D:\Firefox_Installer.exe")
```

But this opens the normal installation wizard of Firefox. Instead I want to run the Firefox installation within the Python command line itself where all installation process should be done inside command line only. Is there any library for that? Source code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it in `Silent` mode with `-ms` argument.

Something like:

```
import os
os.system("D:\Firefox_Installer.exe -ms")
```

More on this [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Installer:Command_Line_Arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Just use double-backslashes( and make sure that the path is right ) :

```
import os
os.startfile("D:\\Firefox_Installer.exe")
```

*P.s. : The version I use is 3.6.5*